# Create a new PDF with content from another PDF in java

Tags: java, pdf

I have a requirement where I need to generate a new PDF file from an existing PDF file.

Input that I need to be able to process: Base64 encoded string of old pdf file, startPage, endPage.

Say for instance - Report.pdf has 100 pages. But I need to create a document from Page 10 to 15 of this Report.pdf.

I tried multiple approaches but not quite able to get through till finish.

any help appreciated.

```
stripper.setStartPage(StartPDF);
stripper.setEndPage(EndPDF);
String result = stripper.getText(doc);
```

Used PDFTextStripper and it is able to get the text content from trimmed file. But I really dont want to get text. I just need those pages in my new pdf.

**Update**:
I have explored PDFBox Library, iText Libraries. The constraint I have is - I am working in Pega Platform which limits my ability to use these libraries. Any other approach if you could suggest?

Comment: Use this: https://pdfbox.apache.org/

Comment: I have a challenge here. I am working in Pega platform. PDFBox library is not fully available.

Is there an alternative to this apprach?

Comment: With PDFBox you could use the splitter class, or the PDFSplit command line application. Please explain what you mean with "not fully available" on that "Pega platform", i.e. what limitations do you have?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see that PDFBox is available but Splitter class not available. (I believe this is available in PDFBox 2.0 version). This is the limitation that I am facing. PDDocument class and its methods were available. But Splitter class is not there.

Comment: It exists: org.apache.pdfbox.util.Splitter in 1.8, and org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.Splitter in 2.0.

Comment: Yes I see that Splitter is available in 8.x version. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified which Pega version you're using, but all modern version of Pega, for example Pega 8, come with the pd4ml library, that can be used for various PDF manipulations.

In Pega create a Java step in an activity rule, where you could try something like this:

1. Create and render an empty PDF document with any Page settings such as Insets
   org.zefer.pd4ml.PD4ML pd4ml = new org.zefer.pd4ml.PD4ML();
   pd4ml.setPageInsets(new java.awt.Insets(0, 20, 15, 30));
2. Decode your Base64 source PDF into an InputStream
3. Create a org.zefer.pd4ml.PD4Document out of that through the constructor PD4Document(byte[] bytes, java.lang.String password)
4. Merge specific pages of this PD4Document into your empty document with the help of the merge function:

   ```
    merge
    public void merge(java.io.InputStream input,
                      int fromPage,
                      int toPage,
                      boolean append)
    Merges conversion result with an already existing PDF document
    Parameters:
    input - PDF document input stream
    fromPage - start page of the existing document (1 or greater)
    toPage - end page of the existing document (-1 means all pages)
    append - 'true' forces to append the existing PDF to the conversion result. Otherwise the existing document will lead the conversion result.
   ```

The full API can be found at https://pd4ml.com/api/index.html

Alternatively you can install external jars such as pdfbox.apache.org into your Pega system and use that in your java step. Jars can be imported through the commandline tool https://community.pega.com/knowledgebase/articles/how-import-or-export-archive-command-line or via the Pega Dev Studio -> Distribution-> Import
This might require a restart.

Comment: I was initially using Pega 7.x. Now we are in 8.x making it better with PDFBox available in libraries. I am checking the option of creating a function using these libraries. However, I have some challenges with it. Once I am good that, will share my solution details. Thank you for your detailed help.